# How do I get access to Python doctest verbose flag inside a test?

Tags: python, doctest, verbose

How do I get access to Python 3.8 doctest verbose flag inside a test?
I see it as `DocTestRunner._verbose` but I would need an instance to grab it from.
I'm trying to do something like

```
def MyClass
  """
  >>> if doctest.DocTestRunner.instance._verbose: printFancyStuffToStdErr() # how do I get instance?
  """
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import doctest, os, sys
  if someCondition(): # n.b. this is simplification and not available inside test
    res = doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
  else
    res = doctest.testmod(verbose=False)
```

NB this is NOT the same as [How can a test in Python unittest get access to the verbosity level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001768/how-can-a-test-in-python-unittest-get-access-to-the-verbosity-level) the answer to which grabs the '-v' or '--verbose' from the command line

Comment: IMHO, doctests shouldn't be that complicated, so you should probably use another test framework instead.

Comment: @wjandrea which other test framework? doctest embeds the tests right inside the function being tested; an excellent place to put them. DRY guides me that determining whether simple or verbose testing should only be run once. So triggering verbose (testing framework, and extra output inside the tests themselves) should be a single process, and the result easily available. Indeed, there is the 'verbose' keyword being used in the call to doctest.testmod(). Exellent! But it's hidden from the very code that needs it. Making local changes to doctest would work but destroys the OTC framework.

Comment: I'm not a testing expert, but I like Pytest, and it can run doctests for you. You might consider [using standard logging and using Pytest's `caplog` fixture to capture it in case of a failed test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html). Unfortunately that does mean having to create separate tests, but on the other hand, it makes the docstrings cleaner (which, keep in mind, is meant to be documentation for your users).

Comment: *"But it's hidden from the very code that needs it"* - I would argue that the "code that needs it" is only the `doctest` module; the code under test shouldn't need it since, like I said, doctests shouldn't be that complicated, but also, it seems like bad practice for the code under test to need access to the testing environment, though like I said, I'm not an expert.